# Connect databricks dashboard to the powerbi service

Tags: python, powerbi, databricks, dashboard

Is there a way to connect my databricks dashboard (which is in view-->dashboard) to the powerbi services?
I have a dashboard in databricks which is having drop down widget and a styler dataframe matrix. I want to connect this dashboard in the powerbi.

I tried to visualize the big 65x65 styled dataframe matrix with the help of python visual. But the matrix was not clearly visible. Also, the css properties that I had assigned to the cells of the styled dataframe was also not clearly reflected.